# using pool.map to apply function to list of strings in parallel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing

I have a large list of http user agent strings (taken from a pandas dataframe) that I am trying to parse using the python implementation of [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-python). I can parse the list fine when only using a single thread, but based on some preliminary speed testing, it'd take me well over 10 hours to run the whole dataset.

I am trying to use `pool.map()` to decrease processing time but can't quite seem to figure out how to get it to work. I've read about a dozen 'tutorials' that I found online and have searched SO (likely a duplicate of some sort, as there are a lot of similar questions), but none of the dozens of attempts have worked for one reason or another. I'm assuming/hoping it's an easy fix.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from ua_parser import user_agent_parser    

http_str = df['user_agents'].tolist()

def uaparse(http_str):
        for i, item in enumerate(http_str):
            return user_agent_parser.Parse(http_str[i])

pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
parsed = pool.map(uaparse, range(0,len(http_str))
```

Right now I'm seeing the following error message:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-25-701fbf58d263> in <module>()
>       7 
>       8 pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
> ----> 9 results = pool.map(uaparse, range(0,len(http_str)))
>
> /home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
>     249         '''
>     250         assert self._state == RUN
> --> 251         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
>     252 
>     253     def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):
>
> /home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
>     565             return self._value
>     566         else:
> --> 567             raise self._value
>     568 
>     569     def _set(self, i, obj):
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
> ```

Thanks in advance for any assistance/direction you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like all you need is:

```
http_str = df['user_agents'].tolist()

pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
parsed = pool.map(user_agent_parser.Parse, http_str)
```

Comment: Thank you! Never imagined it would be that simple.